# Can 2 routers connected with each other with their connected interface belong to different network

Tags: networking, router

I am new to networking and just simulating some network setup with 2 routers which are connected with each other.

```
  PC1---------R1-----------------------R2 ------------ PC2
```

Here is the Ip config :

PC1 -> 10.0.0.2 255.0.0.0

R1 (left interface connected to PC1) -> 10.0.0.1 255.0.0.0

R1 (right interface connected to R2) -> 192.168.1.249 255.255.255.252

R2 (left interface connected to R1) -> 192.168.1.245 255.255.255.252

PC2 -> 20.0.0.2 255.0.0.0

R2 (right interface connected to PC2) -> 20.0.0.1 255.0.0.0

In above right interface of R1 and left interface of R2 are in different network.

Can this be the case when connecting them ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although this is not a programming question, I will answer anyway.

The answer is no. Not if you want to let them communicate with eachother.

Although the class-a networks for connecting the PCs is wasteful and unnecessary, because it is in simulation, it might be possible. Do not connect to the outside world, as 20.0.0.0/11 is owned by Microsoft.

Your R1 interface has the network 192.168.1.249 255.255.255.252. That network has hosts from 192.168.1.249 to 192.168.1.250. That means that R1 can communicate with  192.168.1.250 only.

Comment: So, both the connected interface should be in the common network. Right ?

Comment: Network classes are dead (_please_, let them rest in peace), killed in 1993 (maybe before you were born) by RFCs 1517, 1518, and 1519, which defined CIDR (_Classless_ Inter-Domain Routing). Modern networking does not use network classes.

Comment: @RonMaupin Ok even if CIDR are used, I hope the concept of sharing a common network ID does not get replaced.